# dot notation and accessing module functions using strings

Tags: python-3.x

pretty new to python, so i tried googling around for answers but i was probably googling the wrong terminology.

So here's my problem

i have this

```
objectName ="Account"

sf.bulk.objectName.upsert(dataToSalesforce,externalIdField, batch_size=10000)
```

The above command should send an upsert request for salesforce upserting on the account object, but it gives me the error `{'exceptionCode': 'InvalidJob', 'exceptionMessage': 'Unable to find object: objectName'}`

the problem is it tried to query the object objectName and not Account.

Everything works fine when i use: `sf.bulk.Account.upsert(dataToSalesforce,externalIdField, batch_size=10000)` but in the current use case the object being upserted to may change.

Comment: Try `sf.bulk[objectName].upsert`

Comment: @scottHunter that gives me TypeError: 'SFBulkHandler' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at errors I noticed it used the term attribute, and googling using that term I found I could do this

```py
getattr(sf.bulk, objectName).upsert(dataToSalesforce, externalIdField,batch_size=10000, use_serial=True)
```

that solves the issue.